# Log prices vs log returns

Tags: data-transformation

I am doing a basic analysis for my research, regarding the relationship between the global oil & gas price and the Australian aggregate and sectoral equity markets.

My supervisor has me using EVIEWS 8 courtesy of its availability at university.

My data comprises of price indexes for World O&G price, Aus financial market, Aus O&G market, etc.

My supervisor instructed me to use returns in order to prevent serial correlation in error term, but I'm not entirely sure I have it correct. Could someone clarify please?

I don't really understand the difference between taking ln(Price) and ln(First Difference), and whether ln(First difference) can be taken as the returns of that particular market.

Comment: Log return has different meaning than ln(return). The same goes for ln(first difference). Returns and first differences can be negative, taking logs of them has no meaning.

Comment: You might also want to check out: http://www.symmys.com/node/85

Answer (score 6):

Your supervisor is right.

Log returns are usually not auto-correlated while prices are.

Also, log returns ($\log(P_t/P_{t-1})$) are widely preferred over raw prices or returns in quantitative analysis of financial time series for various other reasons such as normalization (returns of different assets can be compared, their prices usually not), time-additivity, and other conveniences for classical statistics and mathematics.

For small return values (i.e. those usually seen on daily or shorter intervals) the log returns are very close to the raw returns.